Can the same Green's function structure describe both $s$-wave and $d$-wave superconductivity with appropriate gap choices?
In the study of superconductivity, I encountered the following Green's functions for the superconducting state:
$$
\tilde{G}(\vec{k}, i\omega_n) = \frac{G_N^{-1}(\vec{k}, i\omega_n)}{|G_N(\vec{k}, i\omega_n)|^{-2} + |\Delta_{\vec{k}}|^2},
$$
$$
\tilde{F}^\dagger(\vec{k}, i\omega_n) = \frac{-\Delta_{\vec{k}}^*}{|G_N(\vec{k}, i\omega_n)|^{-2} + |\Delta_{\vec{k}}|^2}.
$$

$\vec{k}$: The momentum of the quasiparticles in the system.

$i\omega_n$: The Matsubara frequency, used in finite-temperature quantum field theory.

$G_N(\vec{k}, i\omega_n)$: The normal-state Green's function, describing the system without superconductivity.

$\Delta_{\vec{k}}$: The superconducting gap function, which depends on the pairing symmetry:

For $s$-wave pairing: $\Delta_{\vec{k}} = \Delta_s$, a constant.
For $d$-wave pairing: $\Delta_{\vec{k}} = \Delta_d (\cos k_x - \cos k_y)$, which has angular dependence and nodes.


$\tilde{G}(\vec{k}, i\omega_n)$: The Green's function for quasiparticles in the superconducting state.

$\tilde{F}^\dagger(\vec{k}, i\omega_n)$: The anomalous Green's function, describing the pairing correlations in the superconducting state.
From my understanding, the structure of these Green's functions should remain the same regardless of the superconducting pairing symmetry. However, the gap function $\Delta_{\vec{k}}$ needs to be chosen appropriately:

For $s$-wave pairing, $\Delta_{\vec{k}}$ is constant, as it does not depend on the momentum $\vec{k}$.

For $d$-wave pairing, $\Delta_{\vec{k}}$ depends on momentum, typically modeled as $\Delta_{\vec{k}} = \Delta_d (\cos k_x - \cos k_y)$, to account for nodes in the gap.


My question is:

Can these Green's functions be universally applied to both $s$-wave and $d$-wave symmetries by substituting the corresponding $\Delta_{\vec{k}}$?
For $d$-wave pairing, does this form adequately capture the angular variation and nodal behavior, or are there any subtleties or alternative approaches I should consider?

I am particularly interested in whether this formulation has limitations when dealing with $d$-wave symmetry and if there are better alternatives for incorporating momentum-dependent gap functions into Green's function formalism.

Can you provide a reference, and also explain the symbols a bit?

@TobiasFünke Hi TobiasFünke,,I've edited my question again. I hope this helps! Here's the reference for your convenience:https://arxiv.org/pdf/2406.13076

Thanks. And welcome to physics SE!
